# Example of sequence of function that monotone bounded but not uniformly convergent

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

My attempt is $f_n(x) = x/n$ but I'm stuck here.

Comment: A caution on communication: You did not specify whether you mean (i) each $f_n$ is a monotone function, or (ii) each sequence  $(f_n(x))_{x\in \Bbb N}$ is a monotone sequence or (iii) both (i) and (ii). And you did not specify which possible domain(s) for the $f_n $.... In this subject, when asking a Q it is better to use more words than less, and to divide what you say into separate very short sentences and clauses.  .English grammar (what little there is of it) is slippery .

Comment: If the domain of each $f_n$ is $\Bbb R$ then your attempt is valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classic example: on $[0,1]$, let
$$
f_n(x) = x^n,
$$
then each $f_n$ is increasing and bounded above by $1$, but $f_n$ is not uniformly convergent, since $\lim f_n = \mathbb 1_{\{1\}}(x)\;[x \in [0,1]]$ is not continuous.

P.S. $(f_n(x))_1^\infty$ are also monotonic numerical sequences for every $x \in [0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:
Let
$$
f_n(x)=\begin{cases}
1-\frac1{n}x&\text{ when $x\in[0,1/n]$}\\
0&\text{ when $x>1/n$}.
\end{cases}
$$
Can you  prove the desired properties?

Comment: Did you mean $f_n(x) = 0$ when $x \notin [0, 1/n]$?

Comment: @mattstokes Thank you! Corrected (for functions on $[0,\infty)$).

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Przemyslaw Scherwentke's answer, you can try $(f_n(x))_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ defined on $[0,\infty)$, where
\begin{align*}
f_n(x) = 
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{ if } x \in [0,1/n]
\\
0 & \text{ if } x > 1/n
\end{cases}.
\end{align*}
$f_n$ is decreasing and bounded for each $n$, and $f_n \to f$ where
\begin{align*}
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{ if } x =0
\\
0 & \text{ if } x >0
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
($f$ also defined on $[0,\infty)$).  It should be easy to show that $f_n$ does not converge uniformly to $f$.